# How to use -Path in New-PSDrive : Powershell network drives

Tags: powershell, networking, path, new-psdrive

I've been reading though a lot of different posts describing how to access a network drive in Powershell, and the majority of them suggest using New-PSDrive, and then include some formatting usually looking somewhat like
`New-PSDrive -Name K -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\Server01\Public"`

As someone who started learning powershell very recently, the formatting of -Root hasn't been very clear since there are never any examples of how to use this drive after this single line. I'm trying to access a shared drive, G:, named Groups, and move files to and from it. When I've been moving files before, the path and destination has been written similarly to `"C:\Users\..."`

Why are there two \\'s at the beginning of the root definition? Does Server01 mean G:, Groups, or something else entirely? If New-PSDrive works and K: is created, can I use K: in commands the same way I would C:?

Comment: double-backslash at the very beginning of a path that indicates a UNC path.

Comment: To access the drive, you can use Set-Location \\servername\sharename, with New-PSDrive you are attempting to map a new drive.

Comment: Lastly, you can use the following for moving files. Hope this helps.
`Copy-Item \\servername1\sharename1\filename.ext \\servername2\sharename2`
`Remove-Item \\servername\sharename\foldername\filename.ext`

Answer (score 0):

`\\Server01\Public` is a shared folder called `Public` on a server called `Server01`, this notation is known as a UNC Path.

Once you have mapped the share to a PSDrive using `New-PSDrive -Name K -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\Server01\Public"` you can use `K:` in the same way you would on a directly attached drive such as `C:`

For example `Get-ChildItem K:` to list the contents or

`Move-Item "test.txt" "K:"` to move files to it